# Crystal Report Calculation

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

The system using **VB.NET, SQL**.

IT has two work shifts,
 early shift(8:00AM-6:00pm) and late shift(7:00pm-6:00am)).

Early shift has  early_shift_in(before 8:00AM ), and early_shift_out(after 6:00pm), and late shift has late_shift_in(before 7:00pm) and late_shift_out (after 6:00am).

1. How to calculate overtime hours and specify either the overtime hours are early shift or late shift?
2. where to calculate the overtime hours? is it in crystal report or vb.net?

Comment: actually I designed a crystal report and now want to conduct the calculation and display it in crystal report but I do not know where to do the calculation? I am new in Crystal

Comment: One more thing, the calculation result must show either the overtime hours are early shift or late shift

Comment: For databind in report, are you use procedure? if yes, then give the table structure and write what you have done so far?

Comment: how to you store early shift and late shift in database?